# Routing error '404' in Laravel 5.2 on Apache 2.4.12

Tags: php, apache2, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I am beginner in PHP and Laravel.
I Installed Laravel 5.2, on apache 2.4.12 server. I am able to access the Laravel5 welcome page when I use "http://localhost/laravel/public" in my browser.

I tried to route a new page by adding the following code to apps/http/routes.php

```
Route::get('about', function()
    {
        return 'about page';
    });
```

But this is leading to the following 404 error message. `The requested URL /laravel/public/about was not found on this server`.I am unable to understand the problem, as according to almost all the tutorials/snippets, my code seems correct.
Thanks in advance for the help. Sorry if this question is too dumb (I am a beginner and want to learn)

Comment: Don't just down vote and run, at least tell the reason, why this question is not worth or bad. That will help me to ask better questions or in a better way... Isn't that the whole point of this system...

Answer (score 0):

You have to place the "about page" in your resources/views folder with a name aboutpage.blade.php 
In your routes file to show the page or specifically i should say a view change your code to
`Route::get('about'), function()
{
 return view('aboutpage');
}`

The error you get is because 
1. You named your page with a space in between which is not allowed.
2. For your approach you should place the file in public folder and change the file name accordingly

Comment: I am not trying to return a view in my example. I am just trying to return the string "about page".  I have already tried `Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'Hello world';    
});` which works perfectly fine and returns "Hello world" instead of the welcome view. Hence, I think that you can get an output without creating a view.

Comment: I am using apache 2.4.7 on ubuntu and the about page works absolutely fine. [check this live](http://satoshirps.site/about) . You should try installing a fresh copy of laravel application. Else you can try using `Route::get('/about')....` .BTW this doesn't make any change but you can try.

Comment: Problem got resolved after setting the "/public" folder as root. So, no requirement of fresh install. Just wanted to let you know... thanks for your help.